# Append to DIV only works outside of JQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know some HTML, CSS, and bits of PHP/SQL - but I just can't wrap my head around JavaScript / JQuery, so I apologize in advance if this is a stupid question. I searched the internet for literally **six hours and seventeen minutes** and finally broke down: It's time to ask someone.

### Code that doesn't work:

```
<div id="grid"></div>

<script>
$(function() {
  for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    var $item = $('<div class="grid-item"></div>');
    $item.append("<h3>This is DIV #" + i + "</h3>");
    $("#grid").append($item);
  }
});
</script>
```

### Code that *does* work (same thing minus the function):

```
<div id="grid"></div>

<script>
  for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    var $item = $('<div class="grid-item"></div>');
    $item.append("<h3>This is DIV #" + i + "</h3>");
    $("#grid").append($item);
  }
</script>
```

The non-functional example (top) outputs 4 DIVs **outside/underneath** of `#grid`. The functional example (bottom) outputs 4 DIVs **inside** of `#grid`. See examples here:

Top example output (doesn't work w/ function): https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Fo4O.jpg.

Bottom example output (does work w/o function): https://i.stack.imgur.com/NU7mg.jpg.

**EDIT**: I made `#grid` teal in the pictures so it's easier to see the problem. Also, I'm using Isotope / Masonry, which only works in `#grid`, which is why the functional example has horizontally-aligned DIVs whereas the non-functional example doesn't.

These snippets are isolated bits of my actual code to better-present my problem. I **do** have a reason to use a function, but that's a can of worms. Is there a simple answer as to why I can't append to a DIV when it's within a function?

Thank you!

Comment: jquery has methods of implementing things in a different way to normal javascript. "javascript html append" is not the same as "jquery html append"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both shouldn't work, because you are using `class` in the HTML:

```
<div class="grid"></div>
```

While the code uses `id`:

```
$("#grid").append($item);
```

And both works here:

```css
#grid {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="grid"></div>

<script>
  for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    var $item = $('<div class="grid-item"></div>');
    $item.append("<h3>This is DIV #" + i + "</h3>");
    $("#grid").append($item);
  }
</script>
```

Using function:

```css
#grid {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="grid"></div>

<script>
  $(function () {
    for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
      var $item = $('<div class="grid-item"></div>');
      $item.append("<h3>This is DIV #" + i + "</h3>");
      $("#grid").append($item);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I apologize - this was an oversight when I drafted my question. I updated my question. Sorry for that!!

Comment: I appreciate this response. I actually came to the realization that this code (not included in my example) was causing this to happen. `<script src="//npmcdn.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>`. Which is too bad, because I need Isotope to work. Back to researching I guess!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working version of your function. First off, you're using ID instead of class on the last append. Second, you don't need to prefix variables with $ in javascript, and you should use single quotes to encase HTML (to be able to use double quotes inside html without having to escape them).

```js
$(function() {
  for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    var item = $('<div class="grid-item"></div>');
    item.append('<h3>This is DIV #' + i + '</h3>');
    $('.grid').append(item);
  }
});
```

```css
.grid {
  background: brown;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10em;
  }
.grid-item {
  background: blue;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid"></div>
```